# Linq to Xml: error on saving a document twice

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" standalone="yes"?>
<property_set_list xmlns="myNamespace">
    <property_set symbol_id="Config">   
    </property_set>
</property_set_list>
```

I want to open it, add some property then close it and edit the added property and then save again:

```
var xws = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, IndentChars = TAB };

using (var reader = ReaderCreator())
using (var output = OutputCreator())
using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(output, xws))
{
    XDoc = XElement.Load(reader, LoadOptions.None);
    Namespace = "myNamespace";

    // Append node   
    AppendToNode("Config", "", MAIN_LOBBY_LIST_CTRL_LOCAL_TABLES_COLOR,      
                 318, 8);

    XDoc.Save(xmlWriter);

    // Edit added node
    SetColors();

    // Error here
    XDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
```

}

The property is added. Then saved successfully. Edited Successfully. But I receive the following error on the second save :

```
"Token StartDocument in state End Document would result in an invalid XML document."
```

What can I do here ? Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create another `XmlWriter`. There is no way to reset it and start writing again from the begining of underlying stream.